# How to trace all javascript events on page (mobile browser)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to get a log of all events that are generated on a given page? Printing events' names to console for example would be enough.

The reason is to know what happens on a particular user action (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071397/is-there-a-way-to-see-that-a-browser-window-is-minimized-while-the-user-is-switc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're debugging Mobile Safari, run iOS >= 5.0 in the iOS Simulator and run [iWebInspector](http://www.iwebinspector.com/). In the Timeline tab you should be able to see every event being fired by the browser after pressing the record button.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using google chrome then you can connect your mobile device to your system using USB and in the google chrome try opening
`chrome://inspect/#devices` url.

Under Remote Target, the sites you opened in your mobile browser will be listed. You can click inspect to debug the site.

In the console use [Monitor Events](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/quickly-monitor-events-from-the-console-panel-2/) to track all the events.

for more info, you can check the [Remote debug Android devices](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/)