# $(window).blur() not working properly in smartphone browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an - [online quiz web application](http://cricapp.net/quiz.php?cat=miscellaneous).

After starting a quiz I want the page to refresh automatically when a user changes the tab or minimizes the application.

For this I have used 
`$(window).blur(function(){window.location.reload();});`

Its working fine on laptop but not perfectly on mobile phones (android / ios) especially when I receive a call in between or when I press the home button to minimize the browser.

Is there a way to do it? Please help.

Comment: Maybe this issue follow..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071397/is-there-a-way-to-see-that-a-browser-window-is-minimized-while-the-user-is-switc

Comment: Thank you that link was helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML5 Visibility API to detect when page visibility changes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Modified sample from above url:

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.hidden) {
    // restart your quiz
  } 
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```